# Expected a trailing semicolon (declaration-block-trailing-semicolon)

Tags: postcss, stylelint, cssnext

Trying to use nesting rules via postcss, but getting warnings below. What rules I need to add in stylelint file to fix these warnings?

Here is the css:

```
.count-sec {
    height: 520px;

    & p {
      color:#fff;
      margin: 0;
    }
}
```

Warnings:

```
Expected a trailing semicolon (declaration-block-trailing-semicolon) [stylelint]
Expected newline before "}" of a multi-line block (block-closing-brace-newline-before) [stylelint]
```

Comment: Are you sure that is the CSS responsible for the warnings? I can't reproduce this at https://stylelint.io/demo/

Comment: Looks like I have some bad rule configured in my stylelint but not sure.

Comment: `Expected a trailing semicolon` says that last style in a block needs to have semicolon, too. In your example you always use semicolons (which is good). Are you sure this piece of css you provided in your post is where the error comes from? Errors should also display error origin place: exact line, column and file name.

Answer (score 1):

> Expected a trailing semicolon (declaration-block-trailing-semicolon) [stylelint]

You should change your rule `declaration-block-trailing-semicolon` become `"always"`
(https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/declaration-block-trailing-semicolon/)

> Expected newline before "}" of a multi-line block (block-closing-brace-newline-before) [stylelint]

You should change your rule `block-closing-brace-newline-before` become `"always"`
(https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/block-closing-brace-newline-before/)

Comment: I used declaration-block-trailing-semicolon: null to ignore the rule to fix the issue.

Comment: These rules were removed. Of course omitting the semicolon after the last declaration is legal CSS, but declaration-block-trailing-semicolon could help preventing merge problems.